# How to Use Regex to Route Prefix in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-routing, laravel-5.7

**Brief:**

I have a custom routes group with a dynamic prefix:

```
Route::prefix('{nickname}')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', function($nickname) {
        return view('profile');
    })->where(['nickname' => '[a-z]+']);

    Route::get('/edit', function($nickname) {
        return view('profile.edit');
    })->where(['nickname' => '[a-z]+']);
});
```

As you can see, on each route I check the prefix correctness through a regex.

**Note:** I also used `->where(['nickname' => '[a-z]+'])` to routes group and got an error.

**Error message:**

> Call to a member function where() on null

**Question:**

How can I solve the problem with checking only once?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Route::group` has `attributes` paramether. One of available paramethers is `where`.

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => '{nickname}',
    'where' => ['nickname' => '[a-z]+']
], function ($nickname) {
    Route::get('/', function($nickname) {
        return view('profile');
    });
    Route::get('/edit', function($nickname) {
        return view('profile.edit');
    });
});
```

[More about **Laravel routes** here](https://laravel-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/routing/#route-groups)

Answer (score 0):

use this hope it will help you

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{nickname}','where' => ['nickname' => '[a-z]+']],function ($nickname) {

    Route::get('/', function($nickname) {
        return view('profile');
    });

    Route::get('/edit', function($nickname) {
        return view('profile.edit');
    });

});
```

Comment: I first tried this method and then asked a question. @Shaielndra Gupta

Comment: Current method return `Call to a member function where() on null`