# Laravel route group with variable prefix and where condition

Tags: laravel

I would like to create a route group in Laravel with a variable as a prefix. I need to set certain conditions too. How to do it properly?

I was following docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-group-prefixes but there are only general examples.

This code should create 2 routes: `/{hl}/test-1` and `/{hl}/test-2` where `{hl}` is limited to `(en|pl)`, but it gives an error: `"Call to a member function where() on null"`

```php
Route::prefix('/{hl}')->group(function ($hl) {

    Route::get('/test-1', function () {
        return 'OK-1';
    });

    Route::get('/test-2', function () {
        return 'OK-2';
    });

})->where('hl','(en|pl)');
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Use Regex to Route Prefix in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53077856/how-to-use-regex-to-route-prefix-in-laravel)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `group` call doesn't return anything so there is nothing to chain onto. If you make the `where` call before the call to `group`, similarly to how you are calling `prefix`, it will build up these attributes then when you call `group` it will cascade this onto the routes in the group:

```
Route::prefix('{hl}')->where(['h1' => '(en|pl)'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('test-1', function () {
        return 'OK-1';
    });

    Route::get('test-2', function () {
        return 'OK-2';
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

By analogy with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53078097/6263942):

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => '{hl}',
    'where' => ['hl' => '(en|pl)']
], function ($hl) {
    Route::get('/test-1', function () {
        return 'OK-1';
    });
    Route::get('/test-2', function () {
        return 'OK-2';
    });
});
```

Does this solve your problem?